# Какая разница между «дворцовский» и «дворцовый»?

Tags: морфология, прилагательные

На днях читал статью, в которой использовалось прилагательное «дворцовский». К сожалению, эту статью найти не могу

Сейчас задумался: можно ли вообще применять такое прилагательное, когда есть «дворцовый»?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. В русском языке существуют два суффикса: **ОВСК и ОВ**, поэтому в данном случае мотивирующим словом выступает одно и то же существительное:
   ***дворец — дворц/ов/ый, дворец — дворц/овск/ий.***
2. **ДВОРЕЦ,** м. 1. Здание, являющееся жилищем, постоянным местопребыванием царствующей особы, главы государства, а также членов царствующей семьи. // Отличающееся великолепием и роскошью здание. Зимний д. <**Дворцовый,** -ая, -ое. **(1 зн.)**. Д. парк. Д-ая площадь. Д-ая стража. Д. переворот (насильственная смена монарха придворной партией без непосредственного участия широких общественных сил).
3. Современные словари **не различают значения двух прилагательных**, но  давайте рассмотрим такой пример: *Но когда смотришь на сцены награждения Черненко, тебя опять макают **в брежневско-дворцовский стиль.*** [А. С. Черняев. Дневник (1984)]

Здесь подходит только прилагательное ***дворцовский***, значит, различие в значениях есть.

4. В **Толковом словаре словообразовательных единиц Ефремовой** суффикс **ОВ** — это обычный (самый частотный) суффикс относительных прилагательных, а вот суффикс **ОВСК** имеет дополнительное значение **свойственности.**
5. Можно проверить на примере: ***борцовый и борцовский.***

**БОРЦОВСКИЙ**, -ая, -ое. 1. **к Борец** (1.Б.; 1 зн.). Б-ое обмундирование. Б. ковёр. 2. **Свойственный борцу; такой, как у борца.** (1.Б.; 1 зн.). Иметь б. вид. Принять борцовскую стойку.

В нашем примере ситуация аналогичная. Можно предположить, что более редкое прилагательное ***дворцовский*** используется именно **в значении свойственности**.

Итак, ответ. **Дворцовый** — имеющий отношение к дворцу. **Дворцовский** — свойственный тому, что связано с дворцом. Поэтому использовать эти прилагательные в речи надо внимательно и с пониманием.

**Примечание**

Я полагаю, что надо **со всей ответственностью** относиться к следующим утверждениям: "***Дворцовский — возможное топонимическое прилагательное от Дворцы, Дворцово***...", так эти непроверенные данные уже цитируются в Интернете.

Comment: Эх, зря со словарями возилась, даже спасибо никто не сказал, как другим.

Comment: Спасибо не успел сказать, потому что долгое время был не в сети, а потом спал :D Спасибо за этот подробный ответ. Отмечу как решение))

Answer (score 3):

Огромная.

Погуглив дикое для меня слово «дворцовский», я обнаружила: «Чита, тракт Дворцовский», то есть напрашивается топоним Дворцовск - как исходное. Ну или что-то столь же ономастическое.

«Дворцовый» же - нейтральное ко дворцу:

> Д. парк. Д-ая площадь. Д-ая стража. Д. переворот (насильственная смена
> монарха придворной партией без непосредственного участия широких
> общественных сил).

---

Погуглила ещё... В худлитре встречается фамилия Дворцовский, а в околонаучных сомнительных источниках - и «дворцовский»:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не верьте им, люди!

Comment: Спасибо вам за ответ!

Answer (score 3):

Дворцовый — относительное прилагательное от "дворец".
Дворцовский — возможное топонимическое прилагательное от *Дворцы, Дворцово, Дворцовое* (село), *Дворцовая* (станица, стация), *Дворцовый* (поселок, хутор), например:

[Стародворцовский сельсовет](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%86%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82) — упразднённое сельское поселение в Кочубеевском районе Ставропольского края Российской Федерации (село Дворцовское, хутор Стародворцовский);
[МО СП «Село Дворцы»](https://xn----7sbcahlewbvcg6aifcb7a3a.xn--p1ai/p14aa1.html) Дзержинского района Калужской области.

Использовал это прилагательное Павел Бажов ("колдун уральский бородатый", "уральский кудесник"; а у него — особенный язык повествования, сказный, простонародный).
["Малахитовая шкатулка"](http://loveread.me/read_book.php?id=61595&p=9): *Барин думает, – откуда у ней лошади? где платье **дворцовское**? – а спрашивать все ж таки не насмелился.*
["Железковы покрышки"](http://loveread.ec/read_book.php?id=61595&p=69): *Только для церквей и разных **дворцовских** украшений больше орлец да яшму спрашивали, а в лавках по каменным поделкам вовсе дешевкой торговали.*

Comment: Спасибо за подробный комментарий.

Comment: Дворцовский — возможное топонимическое прилагательное от Дворцы, Дворцово,   У вас есть ссылка на это утверждение, укажите, пожалуйста, источник

Comment: Конечно, есть. Вы невнимательно смотрели мой ответ.

Comment: Сказный? https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/сказовый

Comment: @oleedd Мне понравилось это словечко. Оно мне попалось вот здесь. (https://books.google.ee/books?id=smiiy9W6tUQC&pg=PT236&lpg=PT236&dq=%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9&source=bl&ots=Wi8cBj6c1t&sig=ACfU3U2AjsaXB2m5eLZTfKzBq7n_n8W-xw&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi7mfCgy6D5AhXk_CoKHUPyBf04ChDoAXoECBQQAw#v=onepage&q=%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9&f=false) *Уж не народно-ли-сказный это образ Того, кто вездесущ и всемогущ?*

Comment: Скорее всего, это неверно, ни в одном словаре нет его. В БТС есть только "сказовый" с такими примерами: *Сказовая манера повествования. Сказовый стиль.* Как раз ваш случай.

Comment: Мне нужна ссылка на АВТОРИТЕТНЫЙ грамматический (этимологический) ИСТОЧНИК, где утверждается, что прилагательное произошло от ТОПОНИМА. Укажите еще раз. Если есть суффикс ОВСК, то это утверждение кажется сомнительным. Особенно удивляет слово "возможное". На каком уровне делается это предположение, мне оно кажется ФЕЙКОВЫМ. Приведите, пожалуйста, убедительные доказательства, что это не так, если они у вас есть.

Comment: А что вы можете сказать по поводу "ли" в середине "народно-ли-сказный"? Есть ли правило, разрешающее такое?